# Trying to find how to find how many prime factors have an odd exponent?

Tags: education

Hi I am doing a question for Mathematica and I'm having difficulties.The question is in the prime factorization of n, how many prime factors have an odd exponent? The given n is shown below (very large)

n = 142065190756865870282488068105667182577501738882057884851974445654\
3423237742166396721779311436580070305999267257391443148780739279119880\
6036362837818906515298335482078702168477375932413656083756056968587479\
3126870900658037035232621234336490924847626041243376077191947718333766\
2139781422597901111260689303906160406976537383552880685721245542814240\
4381640394269606051500

The first step I did was to show the prime factorization of the given n,

pf=FactorInteger[n]

but I'm having trouble knowing how to extract the odd exponents and list them in the output.

Answer (score 4):

> but I'm having trouble knowing how to extract the odd exponents and
>   list them in the output.

For purpose of showing this, there is no need to use such a large number (it is taking too long).

```
n = 2434500;
pf = FactorInteger[n]
```

gives

```
{{2, 2}, {3, 2}, {5, 3}, {541, 1}}
```

So all what you have to do is use `Cases` to select the odd exponents

```
 Cases[pf,{x_,y_}/;OddQ[y]:>HoldForm[x^y]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or if you just want the exponent

```
 Cases[pf,{x_,y_}/;OddQ[y]:>y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And if you want to remove duplicate odd exponents that show up, you could always call `Union` on the result.

Comment: Also: `Select[pf, OddQ@#[[2]] &]`